# What's the URL format that shows all comments expanded for all SE sites?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks, api

I want to archive some questions. But some comments are hidden because of the mechanics of how SE's UX work i.e. I have to click on `show X more comments` below each post.

So, like `superuser.com/a/1557718` expands to `https://superuser.com/questions/1557711/how-to-know-the-font-used-in-a-pdf-file/1557718#1557718`,
**What modification can I do in `xyz.stackexchange.com/q/...` so that all comments are visible in each post?**

I tried appending some `?` and `&` based combination, just random tries with assumed terms, but SE sites seem well designed to avoid SQL in URL hacks - so this approach didn't work.

Comment: In case there isn't such a url to show all comments by default, one possible option is to use [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/). Select the site and enter the question id to get the question and answers in a printable format. All the comments are displayed. Of course you can also just compose a query to get all comments using [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Pretty sure that's just not possible. There's a pending feature request [asking to add such a button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289105/expand-all-comments-button).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't exist. If it would exist, it would be a good candidate to be added to my answer on [Documentation for Stack Exchange engine URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332237/295232)

> I want to archive some questions.

I agree it would be easiest to do so by just saving the URL to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/). @KodosJohnson mentions a few solutions in the comments:

- [Stack Printer](http://www.stackprinter.com/) (I haven't tried it)
- [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) - it's [possible](https://web.archive.org/web/20200511180833/https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236884/refresh-timestamp-for-each-stack-exchange-site) to archive SEDE queries if you run them manually first (the Wayback Machine can't defeat the Captcha)

  A possible downside is that SEDE is refreshed only once a week, on Sunday morning
- Since you tagged your question [api](/questions/tagged/api), you can use the [questions by ids method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids) with an appropriate [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) to fetch all relevant data. [Here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=349185&filter=!)rTkraPYPefwELKox66q&site=meta&run=true) is an interactive example, and you can copy the URL and [pass it to the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200610060959/https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/349185?order=desc&sort=activity&site=meta&filter=%21%29rTkraPYPefwELKox66q).

Answer (score 3):

#### Some comments are hidden

There are a couple of different user scripts to expand all comments:

> The following script for Tampermonkey (multi browser) or Greasemonkey (Firefox) automatically expands all comments which are normally hidden behind the "show ... more comments" link:

[Expand all comments script - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/7993/expand-all-comments-script)

> In principle that what Expand all comments script does, but with two
> major differences:
>
> - Scrolls the page back to the initial target of the corresponding link you selected (i.e. to question, question comment, answer or
>   answer comment) after comment expansion (since also "clicking" on a
>   link programmatically – show n more comments in this case – scrolls
>   the page to that link).
> - [internal] Uses regex for @include and @exclude. (Agreed, this prevents the really nice Sites favicons in Tampermonkey's Installed
>   userscripts tab.)

[script - StackExchange – Expand Hidden Comments - Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/8514/stackexchange-expand-hidden-comments)