# (How) should I report someone abusing data from Stack Exchange for spam?

Tags: support, spam, email

### Disclaimer: the email below has turned out to be from the person signed below it

#### The general question in title still stands.

So I got this spam from Gmail address **`address removed since it turned to be legitimate personal gmail address`** (just remove stars to get valid address):

> Hi Tomáš,
>
> Yes, I’m afraid it’s true; I am another recruiter to add to the long
>   list of recruiters who must be contacting you almost daily.
>
> At least some good news is that I am a direct employer and not one of
>   those pesky Recruitment Consultants from an Agency….
>
> I don’t want to waste your time, I’m not going to harass you, I’d just
>   like to know one thing….
>
> If you were considering a change in company, what would the change
>   involve? What would be important to you? And, what would you want to
>   hear from me in order to make you consider a new company?
>
> Ok, I’m obviously not very good at this! That was 3 things; I hope you
>   can forgive me for that!
>
> If you do reply and I think I can match what your needs and
>   motivations are, then perhaps you’ll be happy to have a conversation
>   with me about opportunities at Foxconn DRC in Prague……..
>
> Kind regards
>
> Paul
>
> Paul Myers pmyers@foxconn.cz
>   phone: 420 466056626

Since the `From` field of the email didn't match the mail address in signature, I came to conclusion that the email is fake, presumably recruiter scam of some sort.

It is only on Stack Exchange where I come under name Tomáš Zato, which is actually Czech wordplay. So it is possible that someone farmed some data off Stack Exchange. I do not know if anyone bothers dealing with this kind of spam. But I found it notable because I receive very little emails and this one got through filters. Given that it's expecting reply, it could be dangerous scam.

**I am not asking just about this message.** How can I handle this in general? It's clear that my Stack Exchange username is related to the spam. And Foxconn is a real engineering company. (I have sent them the email in case they were interested)

Comment: [This is against the Terms of Service.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa?rq=1) Contact Stack Exchange, open the sandpit, and let the lawyers play.

Comment: Just a quick check: you didn't had an [developer story public visible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340960/a-post-mortem-on-the-recent-developer-story-information-leak?cb=1)?

Comment: @rene I certainly didn't use the developer story feature. I was already happily employed when that rolled out.

Comment: Off-topic, but yes, Foxconn is indeed a real engineering company. And a quite well-known one, actually, not only from what they make (the iPhone, among other products), but also from their [human resource](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxconn#Controversies) strategies (since we are talking about hiring)...

Comment: Um, isn't it kinda rude to publically show the email and phone instead of showing them just to trusted people (the people you're going to contact)?

Comment: @devRicher Well, that email is public on their website and their recruitments documents. I am sharing the spam as a received it. I also made it clear that the sender was not the one whose address is at the end of the message.

Comment: Sorry then, "pdmyers1975" didn't look like a company email to my eyes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you definitely need to report this. This is something the legal department of Stack Overflow (the company) should be handling. Hence asking here is not going to help (for future reference, I understand you asked how to report this kind of issues).

The best option in such cases is to click the [*contact us*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page. Fill in the form and usually within a week or two you should have a reply (it can take some hops before you receive an answer so be a little patient please).

Comment: Ah. I already trained myself to totally disregard Contact us links on big companies' sites. I'll assemble the info I have and send it to them.

Comment: @TomášZato luckily for all of us, Stack Exchange isn't yet considered a big company.