# What exactly does "links to a legal fund campaign" mean?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, legal, company

I understand that links to a certain legal fund campaign [will be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338270).

My user name had again been changed without notice. For a few days my user name had been a broken-up URL to a short (22-line) text file on Pastebin that I have written. While that text file does include a GoFundMe URL, my user name only "linked" to Pastebin, and I honestly do not understand how that can still be considered "linking to a legal fund campaign".

Does that mean that if I have a personal blog with the campaign mentioned in a blog post, I can't link to my blog anymore?

How far does the prohibition go? If I have a Pastebin file describing a GitHub Gist mentioning a Tweet linking to the campaign, will it still be removed?

I have tried so hard to read the rules, to figure out a way to express my opinions while still abiding by them, but I honestly do not understand how I have broken the rules. Just exactly what is allowed and what is not?

Comment: *How far does the prohibition go? If I have a Pastebin file describing a GitHub Gist mentioning a Tweet linking to the campaign, will it still be removed?* Yes. And since you went through three proxies, you will only be suspended for three years.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi wow, better not use Tor then ...

Comment: @rene, yup, that would probably destroy the universe.

Comment: "*I have tried so hard to read the rules, to figure out a way to express my opinions while still abiding by them*" reads to me as "I have tried so hard to find a loophole." SE has made it clear that "expressing your opinions" in the form of linking to that campaign is not allowed on this platform. Any way you find to do so will be breaking the rules.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to not link to somewhere while still linking to that same somewhere. Sounds like a catch 22...

Comment: No need for links. By now google learned to find this campaign pretty well by itself. But then again many people often show a lack of search capabilities.

Comment: It looks like you are asking SE what loophole you can use to bypass the prohibition SE has put in place. I don't see how that can get a useful or unexpected result. Perhaps you need to clarify your question.

Comment: *...to figure out a way to express my opinions...*. What you can do is keep trying and don't tip your hand by posting questions like these. If you believe you have the moral high ground (as I do) then act like it.

Comment: The Ministry of Truth has decreed that a certain concept does not exist, therefore it is high treason to imply otherwise, however indirectly. (As it has never existed, it is probably also treasonous to imply that it did exist at all, or that this decision was made: FWIW, it was always this way.)

Answer (score 19):

A link is ["a connecting structure"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/link); this includes direct links to said campaigns, but also any indirect constructions **clearly designed** to *connect* users from here to there, even if that involves multiple steps and/or deobfuscation.

> Does that mean that if I have a personal blog with the campaign mentioned in a blog post, I can't link to my blog anymore?

If your blog is relevant to the question or answer, I guess it's not a problem.

Comment: I mean can I still link to the blog from my user profile etc?

Comment: Direct links are removed too, *sometimes*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339235/295232. I haven't heard anything about blogs, but since you're already on the radar, I wouldn't recommend it.