# Add 'Export as Markdown' option to SEDE

Tags: feature-request, markdown, data-explorer, tables

Now that [Markdown tables are a thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/), can we please have an option in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to export the data in a format that's ready to paste in a Stack Exchange post?

I mean, I can do ugly things like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1337480/tables), and check the 'Text-only results' option:

[image]

which produces

| Question | Score |
| --- | --- |
| [A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277369) | 2770 |
| [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965) | 2405 |
| [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526) | 2060 |
| [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) | 1798 |
| [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953) | 1787 |

But it shouldn't be too difficult to add another export option to make our lives easier.

Answer (score 2):

It will take some effort to implement this, specially if you also want to magic links to work.

Until this is done I'll offer this small helper query to produce a basic table quickly. I took your example query and fiddled a bit with the [information_schema and its Columns table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). That will give for any table the columns. I used that to build up an union statement, similar to yours but without having to define the columns, it uses the columns in a result table.

In my example I used a #temp table and therefor I query the tempdb.information_schema. But if you only have a simple projection over an existing table you can use the information_schema from the current database.

Adding or renaming a column in the #result table is now automatically reflected in the generated table.

Here is the [example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1371240?opt.textResults=true)

```
-- build a #result table

select top 5
       id
     , owneruserid
     , creationdate
     , score
     , viewcount as [my col name]
into #result  -- temp table
from posts
order by id

-- generate  markdown table 

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = 'select ''|' + string_agg(column_name, '|') + '|'' as tbl' 
+  ' union all select ''|' + string_agg('-'        , '|') + '|'' as hdr'
+  ' union all select concat(''|'',' 
                           + string_agg(quotename(column_name), ',''|'',') 
                                                          + ',''|'') as row
     from #result' -- temp table
from tempdb.information_schema.columns -- in tempdb
where table_name like '#result%'       -- our temp table name

-- print @sql
exec (@sql)
```

And here is what the table looks like it generates:

| id | owneruserid | creationdate | score | my col name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jun 28 2009 7:14AM | 65 | 3213 |
| 6 | 41673 | Jun 28 2009 8:40AM | 10 | 629 |
| 9 | 6309 | Jun 28 2009 8:58AM | 8 | 293 |
| 10 | 11361 | Jun 28 2009 9:16AM | 13 | 712 |
| 11 | 84671 | Jun 28 2009 9:19AM | 4 | 279 |

Comment: Nice! I never realized that temporary table information is stored in the information schema of the tempdb...

Comment: @Glorfindel it is a bit wonky (notice the `LIKE` ) but I was remembered y'day about its workings when I read about a possible attack vector. So while I checked if that was exploitable I decided to make myself useful ...